# Grouping up multiple values into an array

Tags: sql

So I have a table like so:
EVENTS

| user_id | event_name | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | apple | 00:01 |
| 001 | carrot | 00:03 |
| 002 | apple | 00:01 |
| 003 | apple | 00:06 |
| 003 | carrot | 00:09 |
| 003 | grape | 00:20 |

Where I'd like to group up the data per user_id like so:

| user_id | event_array |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | apple:'00:01',carrot:'00:03' |
| 002 | apple:'00:02' |
| 003 | apple:'00:06',carrot:'00:09',grape:'00:20' |

I've been able to group up by user_id into an array like so:

```
    SELECT 
        user_id, 
        ARRAYAGG(event_name) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY time DESC)
    FROM EVENTS
    GROUP BY user_id
```

but I'd like the datestamp to be next to the event_name, like

```
apple:'00:01',carrot:'00:03'
```

rather than

```
apple,carrot
```

Comment: Take one step back, without worrying about aggregating/grouping yet, and think about how you would structure a SELECT statement so that you get row results such as ``001, apple:'00:01'`` and ``001, carrot:'00:03'`` .... if you can get those results on individual rows, then that should give you the information you need for your aggregation

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating `event_name` with `time` and using `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    STRING_AGG(event_name || ':' || TO_CHAR(time, 'HH24:MI'), ',' ORDER BY time) AS event_array
FROM EVENTS
GROUP BY user_id;
```

**Output:**

| user_id | event_array |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | apple:'00:01',carrot:'00:03' |
| 002 | apple:'00:02' |
| 003 | apple:'00:06',carrot:'00:09',grape:'00:20' |

Try on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bb44e0/1/0).